# Showing time on label according to selected time zone from combobox (VB)

Tags: vb.net, timezone

I wonder how to display the time in a label according to the selected UTC time zone from the list of a combobox. Thanks in advance. This is what  have so far.

```
Private Sub frmClock_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles MyBase.Load

    Label2.Text = TimeOfDay
    Dim tzCollection As ReadOnlyCollection(Of TimeZoneInfo)
    tzCollection = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
    Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = tzCollection

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim selectedTimeZone As TimeZoneInfo = DirectCast(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue(), TimeZoneInfo)
    MsgBox("You selected the " & selectedTimeZone.ToString() & " time zone.")

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim dt As Date = TimeOfDay
    Label2.Text = dt.ToString()



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TimeZoneInfo` class provides several shared methods which can be used to convert times from one time-zone to another.  For instance, if the time from which you want to convert is UTC, you can use the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method, like this:

```
Dim convertedTime As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Date.UtcNow, selectedTimeZone)
```

Or, if the time to convert is in the current local time-zone, then you can use the `ConvertTime` method, like this:

```
Dim convertedTime As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Date.Now, selectedTimeZone)
```

Alternatively, if the source time is in another time-zone (not UTC nor local), you can use another overload of the `ConvertTime` method which takes both the source time-zone and the destination time-zone, like this:

```
Dim convertedTime As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceTime, sourceTimeZoneInfo, destinationTimeZoneInfo)
```

Comment: @user3154600 - If Steven's answer solved your problem, then please  check the box to mark it as the accepted answer, and upvote!